# Using the URLconf defined in TEST_PAGE, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

Tags: django, http-status-code-404

I've reviewed other posts related to my question, but I'm unable to find an answer for my question.

When I try to access "http://127.0.0.1:8000/TEST_PAGE" I get the following error:

"Using the URLconf defined in TEST_PAGE, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
^$
^TEST_PAGE/
The current URL, TEST_PAGE, didn't match any of these."

Here is what I have for Mysite/Mysite/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', include('Main_Page.urls')),
    url(r'^TEST_PAGE/', include('TEST_PAGE')),
]
```

I have the APP installed in Mysite/Mysite/settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'TEST_PAGE',
    'Main_Page',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Here is what I have for Mysite/TEST_PAGE/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^TEST_PAGE', views.index, name='TEST_PAGE'),
]
```

And here is what I have for Mysite/TEST_PAGE/views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'TEST_PAGE/TEST_PAGE.html')
```

The main/index/home app works fine, I'm just trying to access the second app.

I'm new to this, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

By including '`TEST_PAGE`' twice(in both `urls.py`), you have defined a url:

```
/TEST_PAGE/TEST_PAGE
```

So

`django` can find url `/TEST_PAGE/TEST_PAGE` but not `/TEST_PAGE`

Your `Mysite/TEST_PAGE/urls.py` should be:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', views.index, name='TEST_PAGE'), # maps to /TEST_PAGE/
]
```